# OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace without memory pool being maxed out

Tags: java, memory, jenkins, jvm, metaspace

It seems like we ran into a OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace before actually running out of available memory for that pool.

More specifically, we appeared to hit that error as soon as the **committed** amount for that pool reached the maximum, instead of when the **used** amount did.

**Here's the setup:**

We have a Jenkins server running on Oracle Java 8 update 121, and have the following metaspace arguments `-XX:MetaspaceSize=10G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=10G`. We also have Datadog monitoring heap and non-heap pools.

We hit an issue where the Jenkins log indicated that some thread threw an OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace. However, in Datadog at the time of incident, the amount of non-heap used is shown to be very low (graph below).

At first I thought Datadog might be measuring it wrong, but using jconsole I get matching results for current usage (I didn't have jconsole open at the time of incident).

My only other conclusion was that the error originated from trying to allocate more **committed** metaspace, even though there's still plenty of gap between that and the used amount.

Am I missing something about how these memory pools are supposed to work?

**Note:** I'm perfectly aware that this is a pretty large metaspace to have to begin with, and that we likely have a classloader leak somewhere. This is something we hit while trying to investigate that leak.

[image: Memory tracking at the time of incident]

Comment: was the OOM for jenkins JVM itself or one of the build 's JVM it forks off ?

Comment: The OOO was for the jenkins JVM itself